# Unit testing a Solidity Library function with a struct memory argument

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, library, unittesting

I am trying to unit test a Solidity Library contract function using truffle and web3. My simplified Library contract looks like this:

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.16;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

library BrickLib {
    struct ECSignature {
        uint8 v;
    }

    function checkSig(ECSignature memory sig)
    public pure returns(bool) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am attempting to call that function using web3/truffle in my unit test as follows:

```
const v = 1
await brickLib.checkSig.call({ v })
```

When this call is made, I get the following error:

```
Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
```

The same error also appears in the remix UI when I try to call the checkSig method from the user interface by deploying the library contract and entering "[1]" in the parameter. The exact error in Remix is:

```
call to BrickLib.checkSig errored: VM error: revert.
revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.  Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

However, any of the following modifications to the contract rectify the issue:

1. Changing the contract from a `library` to a `contract`.
2. Removing the `memory` parameter completely, even if there are other non-memory parameters present.
3. Calling the `checkSig` function from within another contract that is importing the library contract.
4. Changing the data type of the memory parameter from a struct to a standard type such as `bytes memory`.

I suspect this all has to do with how Solidity [calls library methods](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.8/contracts.html#call-protection-for-libraries) and that the call method changes when memory arguments are introduced, but it is not exactly clear what is happening. Maybe I need to use a `delegatecall` instead of a regular `call`?

As I am writing unit tests for my contract library in Javascript, I would prefer not to have to deploy a second contract using the library in order to test it. I would also prefer to write my tests in Javascript and not Solidity. I'd rather also maintain the use of a struct, as my real code is more complex and structs assist in maintainability.

Comment: +1 for a very-well written question!

Comment: After some testing it has a strange behavior, the same function called from a contract will work, even calling the library from a contract will work. It is just that calling the library directly with a struct param fails, but calling with a uint will work.

Answer (score 0):

Selectors for library functions and external functions are calculated differently:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.17;
import "hardhat/console.sol";

struct ECSignature {
    uint8 v;
}
library BrickLib {
    function checkSig(ECSignature memory sig) public pure returns(bool) {
        return true;
    }
}
contract testcontract {
    function checkSig(ECSignature memory sig) public pure returns(bool) {
        return true;
    }
    constructor() {
        console.logBytes4(BrickLib.checkSig.selector); // 0xfb476b23
        console.logBytes4(bytes4(keccak256(bytes("checkSig(ECSignature)")))); // 0xfb476b23
        console.logBytes4(this.checkSig.selector);     // 0x7a8bd55f
        console.logBytes4(bytes4(keccak256(bytes("checkSig((uint8))")))); // 0x7a8bd55f
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a simple approach?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.17;
import "hardhat/console.sol";

library BrickLib {

    struct ECSignature {
        uint8 v;
    }

    function checkSig(ECSignature memory /* sig */) public pure returns (bool) {
        return true;
    }
}

contract BrickTest {

    function testCheckSig(BrickLib.ECSignature memory sig) public pure returns (bool) {
        return BrickLib.checkSig(sig);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.